# “the that stimulus” Are determiners always mutually exclusive?

Tags: articles

“The drill is initiated on a cue, such as enemy action or your leader's order, and is a trained response to **the that** stimulus.” (FM 3-21.75)

Is such a construction grammatical and stylistically acceptable?
BTW, wouldn’t it be better to use an article before “enemy”?

Comment: I suspect this is an editing mistake.

Comment: No, there does not need to be an article before *enemy*.  *Enemy* here functions as a *noun adjunct*; it modifies *action*.  What kind of action?  *Enemy* action.  So you might ask "Shouldn't there be an article before 'enemy action' anyway?"  But *enemy action* here functions as a kind of general concept; saying "*the* enemy action" or "*an* enemy action" would make it more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's written, the example sentence seems to be a mistake.

---

It's not normally grammatical to phrase a sentence in that way. (Either *the* or *that* should be removed.)

The only exception I can think of would be if **that** were a proper name—like the *Atkins Diet*. In which case, it would be styled as *the That stimulus*—or *the That Stimulus*, depending on how it was named.

Comment: Thanks! But would the meaning change if the sentence read “an enemy action”?

Comment: There would be a slight change in meaning, but it wouldn't affect your main question. Without an article, *enemy action* is a mass noun—it's uncountable. Just like *I am eating cake* doesn't say how much or how many. If you say "*an* enemy action" then you are referring to an actual occurrence of it rather than the idea of it in general. (But also, if you used "*an* enemy action" you'd also want to use "or *one of* your leader's *orders*" in order to maintain parallelism.)